# Using Gorilla Clear Grip behind stove

Tags: repair, tile, adhesive

Can I use gorilla clear grip to adhere marble tiles to Sheetrock behind my stove? New remodel didn’t take tile below counter line and I can see the Sheetrock. I want to put a couple tiles on the wall so I can’t see the Sheetrock behind the stove. Does the flammable warning apply to the cured product as well. I could not find that info on their website or FAQs.

Comment: Usually the flammable warning are for when you use the product and it is curing.  Curing it releases solvents and flammable vapours, and not the best time to be smoking.  If there is a fire after it dries, probably not the best smoke to breath in.  It might stick the tiles on, but most tiles do have specific instructions and products for that job and would try to follow them.

Comment: Why not using regular tile cement, it is not flammable

Comment: And tile cement will last *far* longer. Continual exposure to heat tends to make organic-based glues and cements brittle. Tile cement is inexpensive and easy to use -- just mix some with water.

Comment: I would say if you have some gorilla grip it will work but with that type of adhesive it can take quite a while for it to cure so you may need to support the tiles until dry, it has som flex to it so it may be a good match for behind an oven.